# Android store credentials obtained from keychain api into keystore

Tags: java, android, ssl, keystore, keychain

I have to recover credentials information that is available from KeyChain API and then replicate this information into a Keystore. The idea behind this is that if the credentials are available in the keystore, it should be used. If not available, go to keychain and load new set of credentials.

The implementation to recover the credentials from keychain works fine and I can get the privateKey and the certificateChain.

The `keychainAlias` property is stored in device's sharedMemory once the user selects the certificate for the first time, and it's reused to load the certificate from Keychain.

```
PrivateKey privKey = KeyChain.getPrivateKey(context, keychainAlias);
X509Certificate[] certifChain = KeyChain.getCertificateChain(context, keychainAlias);
```

Once I have this data, I try to store them in a Keystore object:

```
KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("AndroidKeyStore");
ks.load(null);
ks.setKeyEntry(keychainAlias, privateKey.getEncoded(),  certificateChain);
```

But then I get this error:

```
ClientCertificateLoader: Could not save certificate information to keystorejava.security.KeyStoreException: Can only replace keys with same alias: ClientCert12 != ClientCert12_KEYSTOREGRANT_1804289383
```

For some reason, the keychain uses a different alias to store the credentials internally, and when I try to store it in the Keystore using the original alias, the keystore checks that they are different and fail.

Any idea on how to overcome this issue will be appreciated.